# Visual Studio Code C# Project has incorrect assembly (program) path (HPD)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

When I create a C# project within Visual Studio Code v1.16.1, I execute the following commands from a command prompt:

```
dotnet new console -o TestConsoleApp
cd TestConsoleApp
code .
```

Visual Studio then launches with a sample "Hello World" console application.

I have the C# extension by OmniSharp installed:

[image]

But when I attempt to debug the application (F5) I get the following:

[image]
which reads:

> Error launch: program
>   'c:\Dev\VSCode\TestConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\TestConsoleApp.dll'
>   does not exist.

The reason for this is because the `launch.json` specifies the program as

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/TestConsoleApp.dll",
```

But the application, when it loads for the first time creates the path as:

```
~\bin\HPD\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
```

And stores all the appropriate assembly information at that location.

**Why is HPD appearing in the *actual* program path?**  It would appear that it is extraneous, and I used nothing but the defaults when installing.  I can't figure out why it is being added to the path.

If I adjust the launch.json, then everything works fine.  It isn't clear why the "HPD" is being added when the project is created.

Comment: I cannot repro this. I followed the steps you describe, and it worked without any issue. What version of VS Code are you using?

Comment: Version 1.16.1.

Comment: I am on 1.17.0, but I can't imagine that the update would make any difference for you.

Comment: Is there an HPD under the bin in your case?

Comment: No, only Debug. No HPD any where.

Comment: It's the little things.  I find this so maddening as I have no idea where this is coming from.  Even VS Code isn't expecting it to be there.

Comment: Did you add anything to the *.csproj* file? It's like this is trying to build to a different configuration, like debug vs release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156304/discussion-between-jhenderson2099-and-r-richards).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when an environment variable overrides values in the build process. The variable that drives this is `Configuration`.

Check your system and user environment variables if any `Configuration` variable is set. The sample problem applies to `Platform` variables (usually set on some HP laptops).

Comment: There is a `Platform` system variable with the value of `HPD`.  There is no `Configuration` variable (system or user environment variable).  So, now I know where the value is coming from.  

How it is this value added to the `program` property value in `launch.json`?

Comment: I have found that is happening but not sure why the VSCode team uses the Platform variable for Debug only.  You might be able to remove the Platform variable (see the bottom of the link page).

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c4e9c3f-2bf2-436e-80de-e000a7dda8bd/msbuild-and-its-use-of-the-platform-environment-variable?forum=msbuild